# Segmentation fault with g++ (when using to_string twice on NaN)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, g++, nan

Lets assume we have the following setup:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
project(Scripts CXX)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} script.cpp)
```

```
// script.cpp
#include <limits>
#include <string>

void func()
{
    const double x = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    std::to_string(x);
    std::to_string(x);
}

int main()
{
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

When we compile & run this in **Release** mode on Linux using **GNU 7.3.0** we get a segfault:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: .../gcc-7.3.0/bin/g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: .../gcc-7.3.0/bin/g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done

====================[ Build | Scripts | Release ]===============================
.../clion-2020.1.1/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build .../test_scripts/cmake-build-release --target Scripts --
Scanning dependencies of target Scripts
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Scripts.dir/script.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable Scripts
[100%] Built target Scripts

.../test_scripts/cmake-build-release/Scripts
Signal: SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)
```

When commenting out the second to_string (i.e. `//std::to_string(x);`) or when changing `x` to a non-nan value (i.e. `x = 10;`) or when running in `Debug` mode, then there is no segfault.

Is there anything I am doing wrong, or is this a g++ bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is this a g++ bug?

Yes, it's a bug in the 7.x versions:

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86274

It was fixed in version 8 of gcc.